# I want to repeat my function not with time but when my function is answerd.

Tags: javascript, function, variables, repeat

```
        var whichQuestionFunction = function(){
            'use strict';
            whichQuestion = Math.floor(Math.random()*5)+1;
            switch(whichQuestion){
                case 1:
                document.getElementById("vraag")
                break;
                case 2:
                divVraag.innerHTML = "simon says clap your hands"
                break;
                case 3:
                divVraag.innerHTML = "point finger"
                break;
                case 4:
                divVraag.innerHTML = "simon says sing"
                break;
                case 5:
                divVraag.innerHTML = "jump"
                break;
            }
        }; 

        while(correctName === false) {
            Player.name = prompt("What is your name?");
            if(Player.name.match(/^[0-9]+$/) === null){
                correctName = true;
            }
        };

        while(correctAge === false) {
            Player.age = prompt("How old are you?");
            if(Player.age.match(/^[0-9]+$/) !== null){
                correctAge = true;
            }
        };

        var clapHandsFunction = function(){
            'use strict'
            if(2 === whichQuestion){
                 alert("You did good!")
            }else{
                alert("GAME OVER")
            }
        };

        var standUpFunction = function(){
            'use strict'
            if(1 === whichQuestion){
                 alert("You did good!")
            }else{
                alert("GAME OVER")
            }
        };

        var singFunction = function(){
            'use strict'
            if(4 === whichQuestion){
                 alert("You did good!")
            }else{
                alert("GAME OVER")
            }
        };

        var pointFingerFunction = function(){
            'use strict'
            if(1 === whichQuestion || 2 === whichQuestion || 3 === whichQuestion || 4 === whichQuestion || 5 === whichQuestion){
                 alert("GAME OVER")
            } else{
                console.log(Onmogelijk)
            }
        };

        var jumpFunction = function(){
            'use strict'
            if(1 === whichQuestion || 2 === whichQuestion || 3 === whichQuestion || 4 === whichQuestion || 5 === whichQuestion){
                 alert("GAME OVER")
            }
        };

        var nothingFunction = function(){
            'use strict'
            if (3 === whichQuestion || 5 === whichQuestion ){
                alert("You did good!")
            }else{
                alert("GAME OVER")
            }
        };
        whichQuestionFunction();
```

I want whichQuestionFunction to repeat when it is answered. Can anybody help me? Also i want an Array to say first Welkom and when whichQuestionFunction is answered and you won then it has to say Vaarwel.

Comment: Give us a jsFiddle (jsfiddle.net) of your page (HTML, CSS and JavaScript)

Comment: In order to repeat something you can use a while loop? Is it something with the while loop that you don't understand?

Comment: An array can't "say" anything. It's a collection of items. Do you mean that you want to display some kind of welcome message on your page first, and a question text with an input when a user visits your page?